# When Killing form equals a constant times the trace

Tags: lie-algebras

How to find an element $0\not =a\in \mathbb C$ such that $\kappa_L (x,y)=aTr(xy)$ for all $x,y\in L$. Where $L$ is:

1. $A_l$
2. $B_l$
3. $C_l$
4. $D_l,\ \ l>2$.

Why such an $a$ is unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $L$ is simple, any two non-degenerate symmetric invariant bilinear forms are scalar multiples of each other, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. The proof follows from *Schur's Lemma* (compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610099/uniqueness-of-the-killing-form)). Since for simple Lie algebras the Killing form and the trace form are both non-degenerate, there is a unique
$a\neq 0$ such that $ \kappa(x,y)=a\cdot tr(xy)$ for all $x,y\in L$. Actually, the unique value $a$ for each classical Lie algebra $L$ is explicitly known, and listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form). One can also directly prove these formulas, e.g., that $\kappa(x,y)=2ntr(xy)$ for all $x,y \in \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, thereby proving uniqueness of the scalar again. Reference: [This homework](http://www.math.psu.edu/wade/math533-HW2-sol.pdf), exercise $4$.