# Proving that $G=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbb{R})$ is semisimple

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I want to find a reference to a proof of semisimplicity of the special linear group $G=\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbb{R})$ by showing that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ of matrices with trace $0$ is semisimple.

One approach would be to compute the Killing form $B$ of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$. I have seen the statement $B(X,Y)=2d\cdot\mathrm{tr}(XY)$ which would prove semisimplicity of $\mathfrak{g}$ by Cartan's criterion. Any points to a reference to a proof of $B(X,Y)=2d\cdot\mathrm{tr}(XY)$ would be appreciated.

**Edit**: It was not clear from the original post, but what I really want to is to prove that $G$ is semisimple by showing that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple. The proofs of $B(X,Y)=2d\cdot\mathrm{tr}(XY)$ that I have found use the fact that $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, in particular semisimple.

Comment: For $B(X,Y)=2d\cdot tr(XY)$ see this [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728294/when-killing-form-equals-a-constant-times-the-trace). There are other posts, too. One can directly compute this on the basis of the Lie algebra. However, we actually only need that $B$ is non-degenerate to conclude that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ is semisimple. This should be in any book on Lie algebras.

Comment: Even better, $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb R)$ is simple, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598356/how-to-show-that-mathfraksl-n-mathbbr-and-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your help!